# How to do load test web services using java?

Tags: java, soapui, apache-axis, load-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to develop a utility for load testing a web service that's based on Soap xml and Messaging queues. The need is to have the functionality of invoking the utility at a **particular time interval** for testing the service(kind of like heartbeat checking). Till now I have used Loadrunner, Silkperformer and SoapUI for manual testing. But how do I make something like this from scratch so that I can also have my custom Java code in the utility invoked automatically. I want to export the results to an excel file after each heartbeat.

I thought of the possible solution :-

**Write unit tests in java and use libraries like AXIS 2, use the timer class.**

But the problem is that **how do I generate load from the java utility** to the service (Like 100 users). Also, should I use APIs of loadrunner(lr) or soapUI rather than AXIS 2 for web based calls(request and response for the soap xml)?

Please ask for more details if the need arises because I couldn't find a nice implentation or answer to this, it'll help a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To invoke it periodically:

   - [Quartz Sheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
   - Put your Java project under CI solution i.e. [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
   - Use built-int OS mechanisms like [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)
2. To add the load:

   - [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)
   - [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)
   - Use a "real" load testing tool from Java code, i.e. [Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
3. To write results into excel: [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Comment: What APIs should I use to make the calls? Something from Loadrunner or soapUI or just an open source API. Because I need to calculate the time also. I'm avoiding to write my own logic for that due to less accuracy of system time recording.

Comment: Personally I would go for [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/). Some people stick to [Rest Assured](http://rest-assured.io/).

Comment: I doubt if they support SOAP XML or messaging queues?

Answer (score 0):

Java Template Virtual User in LoadRunner